# Django 1.8 BASE_DIR template issue

Tags: python, django, templates, django-admin

I'm new to Django and have encountered an error that really has me stumped.  I'm just putting together a basic site and using the tutorial as a bit of a guide, but I've run into an issue regarding templates.  I created a templates directory in the same directory as manage.py, created an admin directory within templates, and copied / pasted base_site.html within the admin directory as per the tutorial.  I then changed a few of the headers, saved everything, restarted the server, and... nothing.  No errors but no changes.  It's as if I had done nothing.  I've tried the various fixes suggested on here but none seem to work.  It's as if the templates directory is not being found so the app is using the default.  Here are the basics that I have right now:

Directory structure: Project>App, templates>admin>base_site.html, manage.py, etc.

In my settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

and

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

and in base_site.html:

```
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('THIS IS WHAT I CHANGED') }}</a></h1>
```

I'm really hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

Comment: Is your settings file in App folder?

Comment: Settings.py is in the app folder and not the project folder, yes.  The templates folder is in the project folder.

Comment: Btw, your snippet works for me. With default structure of the project (just updated template_dirs).

http://pastebin.com/VvErAizj

Comment: This really makes no sense whatsoever to me.  If I change the BASE_DIR at all the entire site throws errors, so that much has to be correct.

Comment: Someone posted an answer earlier and then deleted it, but that answer was actually correct.  It had to bounce around in the back of my brain for a few hours but it finally clicked, so whoever it was that posted about the default values, please repost so I can give you the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
{{ site_header|default:_('THIS IS WHAT I CHANGED') }}
```

is evaluating `site_header` and if found `False`, will output default. `site_header` is a variable defined in `AdminSite` class. There is no reason from what you describe for `site_header` to be `False`, so `site_header` will be displayed, not the text you changed.

See `Default filter` description:

> **DEFAULT**
>
> If value evaluates to False, uses the given default. Otherwise, uses
>   the value.
>
> For example:
>
> {{ value|default:"nothing" }} If value is "" (the empty string), the
>   output will be nothing.

Here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#default

There are ways to change `site_header`, you can create a custom model based on `AdminClass` and then define `site_header` for this new instance. This means defining a new url as well.

Or you can set site_header:

django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.site_header = "New Header"

Comment: I pulled that straight off of the official Django tutorial... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/